# How to adjust 3 ImageViews in a LinearLayout

Tags: java, android

I defined a LinearLayout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/top_menu"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/backrepeat"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/topLeft"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:src="@drawable/library_top_left">
        </ImageView>


        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/topMiddle"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/library_top_middle"/>

        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/topRight"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:src="@drawable/library_top_right"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

I'd like that one image is on the left side of the screen, one in the middle, and one on the right side. However all of them are on the left side. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a relative layout, and instead of gravity, try android:layout_alignParentLeft=true, android:layout_centerInParent=true, android:layout_alignParentRight=true

```
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/top_menu"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/backrepeat"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/topLeft"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:src="@drawable/library_top_left"/>

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/topMiddle"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:src="@drawable/library_top_middle"/>

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/topRight"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@drawable/library_top_right"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put in `android:layout_weight="1"` into each of the image views. Supply padding/margin to make it better.

Comment: it looks better now, but however, the images are not really on the right corner but some pixels away from the border.

Comment: The pics will be streched and I don't think it is the goal here

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html).